# How can I set a special character(right arrow) in UILabel?

Tags: xcode, uilabel

I am trying to set a text in UILabel, like this

mylabel.text = @"▶ section1";

but, the right arrow character is translated to audio player icon inside UILabel.

Is there a way to print right arrow character intactly as it is.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using unicode:

```
mylabel.text = @"\u25BA section 1";
```

Comment: Sparks, I am unfamiliar in using this site. Should I pick up one of postings as answer? if so, where is the button for selecting yours to Answer?